# Preprocessor definitions going haywire. int define redefinition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, c-preprocessor

I am trying to add a preprocessor definition so that a value is only defined while a certain project is building, then it becomes undefined.  I have gone into my project properties -> preprocessor -> preprocessor definitions.  In here, I typed `#define PROJECTNAME_EXPORT`, in hopes that I could call `#ifdef PROJECTNAME_EXPORT` throughout that project to swap out a value (between dllexport and dllimport) on build-time.

However, when I hit okay, it looks like visual studio adds a double quote before my definition.  When I try to build, I get over 100 errors, mostly saying "illegal escape sequence".  Others of note are "int define: redefinition", "int MYPROJECT_EXPORT redefinition", etc.  Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't include the "`#define`" in the definition. Just the name of the symbol, and optionally a value, like so:

```
PROJECTNAME_EXPORT=coolness
```

The way to think of the definitions you enter here, into the IDE, is that they will be passed to the compiler using the [/D option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8%28VS.80%29.aspx), so the syntax ought to be close. There would be no need to include the `#define` syntax, since these definitions are handed to the compiler/preprocessor not in C source, but through a different mechanism.